# Alternative for ShowOptionDialog in Java

Tags: java

So currently I have

```
    public boolean start(){        
        boolean validInput = false;   
        String input = null;
        int nextMove;
        Object[] options = { "Move Hek", "Move Back", "Exit Game" };
        int newEnemyAtMoveNo = 0;
        do{
            displayCharPositions();
            if(!checkOgreAlive()){                
                System.out.println("Ogre Dead!!");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hek Died! \nGame Over!");
                return false;
          }
            input = Array.get(moves, new Random().nextInt(8)).toString(); 

                    nextMove = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What will you do next? " + Ogre , "Your move",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                    null, options, options[0]);
            if(nextMove == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {           
                validInput = moveCharacter(Ogre,input);
                if(!validInput){
                    if(!input.equals("E"))
                        System.out.println("Invalid move! Try Again");
                }
                else {                
                    moveNo ++;
                    System.out.println("Move No.: " + (moveNo+1));
                    moveEachEnemy();
                    if(moveNo % 3 == 0)                    
                        newEnemyAtMoveNo = new Random().nextInt(3);                
                    if(moveNo % 3 == newEnemyAtMoveNo)
                        enterNewEnemy();                
                }}
        }while(nextMove != JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION && nextMove != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
        int saveResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to save the game?", null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(saveResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
```

Is there an alternative to a pop up box, for example can I put button on the Gui to replace the input box?

However, if I don't have something stopping the loop (e.g the showMessageDialog) the program runs to completion.

So basically, can I have the same functionality as the showMessageDialog but with the buttons on the Gui instead of a box popping up?

Comment: Yes but you'll need to define a new `JDialog` or `JFrame` with your own control, that interact with your previous fram.

Comment: Is it not possible from the current JFrame? because it has other controls that will be implemented that need to be accessible at the same time and i'd rather not have two windows open at the same time

Comment: in fact you can do whatever you want to add a button I think you can refer to the java gui totrial from SUN / ORACLE